# How to wrap inline-flex div content such that the wrapped portion occupies empty space below the previous inline-flex div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.red {
  border-color: red;
}

.green {
  border-color: green;
}

.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  border-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  border-color: pink;
}

.brown {
  border-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-group">     
    <div class="box red">R</div>
    <div class="box green">G</div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-group">     
    <div class="box blue">Bl</div>
    <div class="box yellow">Y</div>      
  </div>
  
  <div class="button-group">     
    <div class="box pink">P</div>
    <div class="box brown">Br</div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Actual:

[image: Actual output]

^ If there is only one `box` in the first `button-group` and two `box` in the second `button-group` then all three occupy the first line. However, as soon as you add a third `box` to the second `button-group`, all of its three `box` move to the next line. Instead of that happening, I want the `box` to occupy any available space on the lines, regardless of which `button-group` they belong to.

Expected:

[image: Expected output]

Overall expectation: There could be *n* number of inline-flex divs inside `container` and *m* number of `box` inside `button-group`. Any `button-group` or any `box` could be removed dynamically. At the end, there must be three `box` on each line, or as many as possible w.r.t. to available width.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the button-group using `display:contents` and move `display:flex` to the container

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
}

.button-group {
  display: contents;
}

.box {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.red {
  border-color: red;
}

.green {
  border-color: green;
}

.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  border-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  border-color: pink;
}

.brown {
  border-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-group">     
    <div class="box red">R</div>
    <div class="box green">G</div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-group">     
    <div class="box blue">Bl</div>
    <div class="box yellow">Y</div>      
  </div>
  
  <div class="button-group">     
    <div class="box pink">P</div>
    <div class="box brown">Br</div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to work better than @A Haworth's solution as this one doesn't auto add extra space between the boxes. Although it didn't work initially as there is a custom HTML tag between the `.button-group` and the `.container` in my actual markup. I fiddled with the CSS a bit and it seems adding `display: contents` to the intermediate tag too worked. So, it's now like: `container(display: flex) > custom-html-tag(display: contents) > button-group(display: contents) > box`. Is it the correct way in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the flex and make the button-groups display inline but their children display inline-block (so they both display inline and take up the given dimensions) you get the required result.

**UPDATE**: to remove the space between the boxes, set and reset the font-sizes as below:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.button-group {
  display: inline;
}

.box {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
}

.red {
  border-color: red;
}

.green {
  border-color: green;
}

.blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  border-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  border-color: pink;
}

.brown {
  border-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-group">
    <div class="box red">R</div>
    <div class="box green">G</div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-group">
    <div class="box blue">Bl</div>
    <div class="box yellow">Y</div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-group">
    <div class="box pink">P</div>
    <div class="box brown">Br</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, too. Although your solution works, it ends up adding extra space between the boxes, but it may come handy in some other scenarios.

Comment: @Deepak, thanks for pointing that out. There's no problem with removing the spaces (which the system calculates depending on the font-size) - the snippet has been updated to remove the space between boxes.